Sumsub font customization does not work on android
I'm trying to change fonts in the Sumsub SDK,
I did everything according to the documentation on IOS all styles work and including fonts, on Android also everything works except fonts
const launchSNSMobileSDK = () => {
    let snsMobileSDK = SNSMobileSDK.init(data?.sumsubSdkToken, () => {
      // this is a token expiration handler, will be called if the provided token is invalid or got expired
      return trigger();
    })
      .withTheme(sumsubStyles)
      .withHandlers({
        // Optional callbacks you can use to get notified of the corresponding events
        onStatusChanged: (event: any) => {
          console.log(
            'onStatusChanged: [' +
              event.prevStatus +
              '] => [' +
              event.newStatus +
              ']',
          );
          if (event.newStatus === 'Pending') {
            setTimeout(() => {
              dispatch(idVerificationActions.setOnfidoDone(true));
              setLoading(false);
              onOnfidoDone();
              trackEvent(EventKey.IDCHECK_SUBMITTED, addPrefixToKeys({}));
            }, 1000);
          }
        },
        onLog: (event: any) => {
          console.log('onLog: [Idensic] ' + event.message);
        },
        onActionResult: (result: any) => {
          console.log('onActionResult: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
          // you must return a `Promise` that in turn should be resolved with
          // either `cancel` to force the user interface to close, or `continue` to proceed as usual
          return new Promise((resolve) => {
            resolve('continue');
          });
        },
      })
      .withDebug(true)
      .withLocale('en') // Optional, for cases when you need to override the system locale
      .withPreferredDocumentDefinitions({
        IDENTITY: {
          idDocType: identificationDocument,
          country:
            jurisdiction === 'GB'
              ? OnfidoCountryCode.GBR
              : OnfidoCountryCode.USA,
        },
      })
      .build();

    snsMobileSDK
      .launch()
      .then((result: any) => {
        // dispatch(idVerificationActions.setOnfidoDone(true));
        // setLoading(false);
        // onOnfidoDone();
        console.log('SumSub SDK State: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
        trackEvent(EventKey.IDCHECK_COMPLETED, addPrefixToKeys({}));
      })
      .catch((err: { code: string; message: string }) => {
        // setLoading(false);
        // if (err.code !== 'userExit') {
        //   dispatch(
        //     commonActions.setNotification({
        //       type: 'error',
        //       text: t('common.formMessages.globalError'),
        //     }),
        //   );
        //   Logger.error('Error with Onfido SDK', {
        //     type: Logger.Type.interface,
        //     payload: {
        //       res: err.message,
        //     },
        //   });
        // }
        console.log('SumSub SDK Error: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
      });
  };

This is my sumsubStyles.json file with styles and fonts
{
  "universal": {
    "fonts": {
      "assets": [
        {
          "name": "Raleway-Bold",
          "file": "assets/fonts/Raleway-Bold.ttf"
        },
        {
          "name": "Raleway-Medium",
          "file": "assets/fonts/Raleway-Medium.ttf"
        }
      ],
      "headline1": {
        "name": "Raleway-Bold",
        "size": 26
      },
      "headline2": {
        "name": "Raleway-Bold",
        "size": 20
      },
      "subtitle1": {
        "name": "Raleway-Bold"
      },
      "subtitle2": {
        "name": "Raleway-Medium"
      },
      "caption": {
        "name": "Raleway-Bold",
        "size": 13
      },
      "body": {
        "name": "Raleway-Medium",
        "size": 13
      }
    },
    "colors": {
      "navigationBarItem": "#000000",
      "contentStrong": "#000000",
      "contentWeak": "#000000",
      "contentNeutral": "#000000",
      "contentLink": "#944BFE",
      "cameraBackground": "#000000",
      "bottomSheetHandle": "#000000",
      "iconRotate": "#000000",
      "primaryButtonBackground": "#000000",
      "primaryButtonBackgroundDisabled": "#000000",
      "primaryButtonBackgroundHighlighted": "#474747",
      "secondaryButtonContent": "#000000",
      "secondaryButtonContentDisabled": "#000000",
      "secondaryButtonContentHighlighted": "#000000",
      "secondaryButtonBackgroundHighlighted": "#e6e6e6",
      "contentInfo": "#18B494",
      "backgroundCritical": "#FFFFFF",
      "backgroundCommon": "#FFFFFF",
      "cardBorderedBackground": "#F6F7F9",
      "backgroundNeutral": "F6F7F9",
      "verificationStepCardStyle": "plain",
      "cardPlainBackground": "#F6F7F9",
      "fieldBackground": "#F6F7F9",
      "fieldContent": "#333C4D",
      "fieldPlaceholder": "#94A0B8",
      "bottomSheetBackground": "#FFFFFF",
      "primaryButtonContentDisabled": "#FFFFFF"
    }
  },
  "ios": {
    "metrics": {
      "commonStatusBarStyle": "default"
    }
  }
}

This is the error I encounter when opening Sumsub on the emulator, and accordingly the fonts are not applied
